# Mapping tables using Entity Data Model

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework. I already have existing database. I managed to map my database tables and generate c# classes but i have a few questions.

1. Is there any way to generate code for a few tables into single file?
   It would be very helpful for me to have i.e user related classes in
   single file.
2. My next question refers to updating model from database. When i
   change name of field in database and update model I have new field
   that was added after refreshing. Unfortunately old field still
   remains in my entity and I have to remove it manually.

   Is there any solution to tell VS to remove these invalid fields from entities?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Your actual code files are being generated from a t4 template. You can use whatever template you want to generate them. To do so right click on the canvas in .edmx file and choose "Add code generation item". It will add a couple of *.t4 files to your project. There are some templates available in nuget package manager. You can even manually edit them (though they are VERY difficult to understand)

2) You can delete the whole table and then re-add it when updating model from database.

Also, take a look at "Code first" approach. You basically create a bunch of poco classes and then subclass DbContext:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MyCoolEntity> MyCoolEntities { get; set; }
    /* ... */
}
```

No .edmx files needed. Entity framework will take care of the database for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already tried Code first approach but my models might change quite a few times because i recently started developing my application. This causes errors when i try to do something with changed model. I also know about code first data migrations but i have not tried this yet.

Comment: Mark my answer as accepted if you like it.
Code first supports [Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591621) which allow you to seemlessly update your database